# ggplot2 no plot becase ggsave no save

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, windows-7-x64

I have a python script using the pyper library (pipes to R), and I am trying to get some output out of ggplot2.  I have tried both the 'ggsave' method and the 'device(...); dev.off()' methods and nothing is output.

I have to use pyper because of using 64 bits everywere (python and R), so rpy[2] isn't an option for me.

The code looks like the following:

```
r("png(filename='test.png',width=720,height=540)")  #comment if ggsave
r("p<-ggplot(DB,aes(X,Y,group=cfg))")
r("""p <- p + geom_path(aes(colour=factor(f1))) + scale_x_log10('X label') +
  scale_y_continuous('Y label',breaks=myb,labels=myl) + 
  geom_point(data=subset(DB,pts==dot),aes(colour=factor(f1),size=factor(f2),
  shape=factor(f3))) + labs(colour='l1',size='l2',shape='l3')""")
r("print(p)")
# r("ggsave(filename='test.png',width=10,height=7.5)   #comment out if using png
r("dev.off()")                # comment if using ggsave
```

No file is created in either case.  I have checked to make certain that the DB data table has entries (1000s).  What could I try?

Comment: Do you what directory 'test.png' would be written to?  What does `getwd()` return?  I'm wondering if it is being written, but not to where you think.

Comment: Found an R problem with loading the library, but the ggsave method still does not update the files (nothing happens to them).  The png method touches the files, but there is nothing in them (all 1k with an updated time.

The getwd() returns the directory I start the python script from, and a search of my system didn't find any other 'test.png' files.

Thanks!

Comment: Have also tried to use the PDF device, with the same results.

Comment: try using qplot instead of ggplot. in the pass i had similar problems. r("png(filename = "test.png", width = 400, height = 400, units = 'px'); qplot(main="title")+xlab("x")+ylab("y")+(....);dev.off()")

Comment: I don't have any ideas why this would happen that way, but some strategies to try and isolate where the problem is.  Simplify your ggplot call to just `p<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt,mpg))+geom_point()` and see if that works (is it your data or not).  Try the `png` approach with just `plot(1:10)` (is it ggplot or all graphics). Run various versions of the R code directly in the R console (is it the pyper library). These should help you know where the problem arises.

Answer (score 2):

So this all turns out to be an issue with libraries and environment variables.  Some of the loaded libraries, like ggplot2, don't load all dependencies, like the digest library.  This error only occurs on the "print(p)" portion of the code.

In addition, there are differences in the x64 library locations that need to be set correctly.  Make certain that the R_HOME and R_LIBS variables match your configuration.

Pyper didn't appear to tell me that libraries didn't load, it just kept going, so qplot wasn't loading in R initially.  After getting that loaded in the right place, you need to make certain you are using either your user account always or the administrator account always (or you have have multiple paths in R_LIBS, but I didn't try that).

qplot and ggsave worked fine, so long as the libraries were loaded.

Thanks for all the dedicated folks and the directions for debug!

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. I would let the maintainers of pyper know about this since loading a library should load all of its dependencies.